# Creating a function that outputs a dictionary with random values

Tags: python

I need to create a function rand_dict(keys=ascii_lowercase) that  that returns a dictionary with the letters of keys as keys and a permutation of the letters of keys as values. Here is what i got

```
import string
import numpy as np

keys= 3

def rand_dict(keys):
    list1 = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    list2 = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    np.random.shuffle(list2)
    return dict(zip(list1, list2))

print(rand_dict(keys))
```

I get the correct output - however as you can see, i am not using the keys value anywhere. How do I setup the function to call it as needed.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `random` instead of `numpy`...?

Comment: no reason other than less code is one preferred over the other -(less overhead i would guess)

Comment: `random` has much less overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `keys` when constructing `list1` and `list2`:

```
def rand_dict(keys = string.ascii_lowercase):
    list1 = list(keys)
    list2 = list(keys)
    np.random.shuffle(list2)
    return dict(zip(list1, list2))
```